# Calling model method from controller "Call to a member function ... on a non-object", but works when called from view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Having the dangdest time calling a model method from a controller function. After many hours, and reading many, many articles on "**Call to a member function ... on a non-object**" and "**Undefined property: Main::$form_model**", etc., I have not found any solution (obviously, or I would not be reaching out here). Just letting you know I'm not trying to take the Easy Pass lane with this question.

My model folder contains this model:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Form_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function update_profile(){
        $data = array();
        $formValues = $this->input->post();
        $this->db->where('member_id', $data['member_id']);
        $this->db->update('members', $data); 
    }


}
```

In my Main class controller, I am loading helpers/libraries/models like this:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
        $this->load->helper(array('cookie','form','url'));
        $this->load->library('../controllers/accessories');
        $this->load->model(array('registration_model','form_model'));
     }
```

These load properly. I know they load properly, because if I change any letter of any model, CodeIgniter throws up an error that it can't load the model.

The last function in my Main class is associated with a form's action  page. The form page is an outer view (in the "views" folder), which also calls an inner view with the same name, but which resides in a "views/content" folder, like so:

```
<?php $this->load->view("top"); ?>
<!-- CONTENT BEGIN -->

<?php $this->load->view("content/profile_management"); ?>

<!-- CONTENT END -->
<?php $this->load->view("bottom"); ?>
```

You can see the "content" middle of this template sandwich invokes a third level view, and in the case where `$role == 1` , that would be "forms/profile_manager_form":

```
<?php 
if ($this->uri->segment(3) === FALSE){
    if($this->input->cookie('member')){
        $member_id = $this->input->cookie('member');
    }
    else{
        $member_id = 0;
    }
}
else{
    $member_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
}

$query = $this->db->get_where('members', array('member_id' => $member_id));
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    $role = $row->role;
}
switch($role){
    case "1" :
        $this->load->view('forms/profile_manager_form');
        break;
    case "2" :
        $this->load->view('forms/portfolio_manager_analyst');
        break;  
}
?>
```

When the profile update form is submitted, the action page is "profile_form":

```
<?php $this->load->view("top"); ?>
<!-- CONTENT BEGIN -->

<?php $this->load->view("content/profile_form"); ?>

<!-- CONTENT END -->
<?php $this->load->view("bottom"); ?>
```

This page, in the "views" folder, itself calls a second-level view in the "views/content" folder, called "profile_form":

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
    echo "$k = $v <br>";
}

$this->form_model->update_profile();
?>
```

...as you can see, I have placed the call to `update_profile` here, and it works. But I don't think I want to build this website with a mish-mash of some model functions called from my controller Main class, while other model functions are called from within view pages, because that's the only place they seem to work.

In my controller's Main class, my last function is where I think the function call should be placed:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
        $this->load->helper(array('cookie','form','url'));
        $this->load->library('../controllers/accessories');
        $this->load->model(array('registration_model','form_model'));
     }

     public function index()
     {
        $config = array();
        $root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $root .=     str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        $config['base_url']    = "$root";
        $data = array();
        $data['scripts'] = $this->accessories->getScripts($config);
        $this->load->view('home',$data);
     }

     public function profile_form(){
        $config = array();
        $root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        $config['base_url'] = "$root";
        $data = array();
        $data['states'] = $this->accessories->states();     
        $data['scripts'] = $this->accessories->getScripts($config);
        $this->form_model->update_profile(); //I want to put my model function call here, but CI gives me the "not an object" error.
        $this->load->view('profile_form',$data);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**
See my answer, below.

Comment: wow, some story... maybe try shortening your answer to show only the necessary parts without which we wouldn't be able to help, many people would not read a question so long

Comment: I gave the right amount of information for that "special" person who can actually help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out that the order of loading of objects in the __construct is important. This has been driving me nuts. I researched "Is there a load order for modules helpers libraries?" and I didn't find anything. But, it does make a difference.

Here was one of my original parent __constructs:

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    // Your own constructor code
    $this->load->helper(array('cookie','form','url'));
    $this->load->library('../controllers/accessories','form_validation');
    $this->load->model(array('login_model','registration_model','form_model'));
 }
```

I simply went by alphabetical order, "h" for helper, "l" for libraries, and "m" for model.

I encountered the "Not an object" error yet again, on a different method of a different model (method **validate()** in object **login_model**). This was really starting to beat me down.

What else could I do, knowing that my models and methods were syntactically correct, and knowing that I was calling them correctly, and especially scouring the web on this problem and coming up short? So, I shuffled the load order of models/libraries/helpers, like so:

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    // Your own constructor code
    $this->load->model(array('login_model','registration_model','form_model'));
    $this->load->helper(array('cookie','form','url'));
    $this->load->library('../controllers/accessories','form_validation');
 }
```

...and now I don't get the error, and my methods work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to load model

```
$this->load->model('registration_model');
$this->load->model('form_model');
```

Comment: Actually, you can load models using an array (at least you could before the last version, I didn't check it if it's still the same)

Comment: Yeah, I've tried both ways, makes no difference to the error I'm getting.